# Whitespace in React.js code affecting state of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to understand reducers in React from [React documentation](https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer).There is a example that writes a task app that could add, delete and edit the task. Here's the [source code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/t7jwxq?file=/TaskList.js&utm_medium=sandpack) provided by documentation

In the Task component, I changed the following code from:

```
    taskContent = (
      <>
        {task.text} 
        <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)}>Edit</button>
      </>
```

To:

```
    taskContent = (
      <>
        {task.text} <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)}>Edit</button>
      </>
```

Then, the resulting app would have a incorrect scope. By clicking the Edit button, the checkbox will be clicked as well. How could a whitespace in code affect such scope?

I have tried to replicate a similar logic with pure JavaScript and HTML. The edit button will not affect the checkbox as expected. The code is below:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Task Entry</title>
</head>

<body>

    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="handleTaskChange()" />
        <span id="text">Sample Task</span>
        <button id='edit' onclick="toggleEditingMode()">Edit</button>
        <button onclick="handleTaskDelete()">Delete</button>
    </label>


    <script>
        function toggleEditingMode() {
            const taskText = document.getElementById(`text`);
            const editButton = document.getElementById(`edit`);

            if (taskText.contentEditable === 'true') {
                taskText.contentEditable = 'false';
                editButton.textContent = 'Edit';
                handleTaskChange();
            } else {
                taskText.contentEditable = 'true';
                taskText.focus();
                editButton.textContent = 'Save';
            }
        }

        function handleTaskChange() {
            // edit logic goes here
        }

        function handleTaskDelete() {
            const taskEntry = document.getElementById(`text`).parentNode;
            taskEntry.parentNode.removeChild(taskEntry);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```